# The solvability of a Hölder ODE

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations

The problem is follow, I want to know weather there is a function $u\in \text{C}^{0}\left((-1,1)\right)$ but not $\text{C}^1((-1,1))$, such that $\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{|u(x+h)-u(x)|}{\left|h\right|^{1/2}}=\sqrt{|x|},\forall x\in(-1,1)$.

I get this problem while constructing a counterexample for the problem:

If $\alpha+\beta=1,u\in\text{C}^{0,\alpha}(\Omega),$and $v=\frac{u(x+he)-u(x)}{|h|^\alpha}\in\text{C}^{0,\beta}(\Omega)$,where $e$  is a unit vector and $h$ is a small real number, then $u \in\text{C}^1(\Omega)$.

Comment: Your second statement is rather strange. If $u$ is an arbitrary function from $\text{C}^{0,1/2}(\Omega)$ then $v\in \text{C}^{0,1/2}(\Omega_h)$, $\Omega_h=\{x\in\Omega\,|\,\text{dist}(x,\partial \Omega)>h\}$. But, generally speaking, $v$ wouldn't belong to $\text{C}^{1}(\Omega_h)$.

Comment: You are right.I just want to construct such a function. And the function $u$ satisfies the equation I described is one.

Comment: I think I made a mistake. There should be a exponent $\alpha$.

Comment: For any such function the right derivative would be equal $+\infty$ for $x\ne0$:
$$
\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{u(x+h)-u(x)}{h}=
\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0^+}\sqrt{|x|}{h^{-1/2}}=+\infty.
$$
So it is not of $C^1$.

Comment: You are right. But what I need is the existence of such a function.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such function. Any function with the property postulated would be monotone increasing on (0,1). But then it would have to be differentiable almost everywhere, which contradicts the assumption.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is helpful. But what if I don't need $u$ to be monotone increasing on $(0,1)$. Just like the question I change,$\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{|u(x+h)-u(x)|}{\left|h\right|^{1/2}}=\sqrt{|x|},\forall x\in(-1,1)$. Then $u$ may not be monotone increasing, in this case.